# Reformat date in SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, date, sql-loader

I am loading Oracle tables using SQL Loader and I have an issue with date formats. The CSV files with the data contain strings in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, but the Oracle tables require date format of DD-MON-YY.

I am currently going through the CSV files line by line to look for and reformat any dates before the load, but the files can reach 10M+ rows and this can be a pretty slow process. Does SQL Loader allow date reformatting in the load?

I'm looking for something like

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'data.csv'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COL1,
COL2,
CREATED_DATE DATE 'DD-MON-YY',
LAST_UPDT_DATE DATE 'DD-MON-YY
)
```

I've read suggestions that this DATE command can format dates automatically but has given no luck so far.

Comment: Are `created_date` and `last_updt_date` declared in the database as `date` data types?  If so, they do not have a format.  Your control file should specify the format of the date strings in the data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `created_date` and `last_updt_date` are actually defined as `date` in the database, they don't have a format.  They're stored in an internal packed binary format that is not human readable.

Your control file needs to specify the format of the strings in the flat file that represent the date.  You say the format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" but that doesn't make sense.  Minutes are MI not MM so I assume that is a type.  HH is a 12 hour time format but that doesn't make sense without an AM/PM indicator.  So I'm guessing your strings are using a 24 hour time format which is HH24.  So my guess is that you want

```
CREATED_DATE DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense. Good to know the most costly process is no longer needed!